# How can I create a new site in IIS6 using a deployed package from VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, iis-6, windows-server-2003, webdeploy

I'm a novice in this, I just created an ASP.NET web app with Visual Studio 2010, I took the folder with all the files and put it on Windows Server 2003 IIS6, I added a new site, and gave all the proper permissions and the site worked, OK, now I need to do the same but with my project being compiled; on Visual Studio I went to Project -> Build Deployment Package...these files were created in the Package folder:

**1. PackageTemp(folder)

 2. myProject.SourceManifest.xml

 3. myProject.deploy-readme.txt

 4. myProject.deploy.cmd

 5. myProject.SetParameters.xml 
 6. myProject.zip**

What do I do with this? I'm used to see a jar file out of my project when I look for a compiled project on Java(which I often program with), but I'm lost with Visual Studio and ASP.NET on compiling projects, could you help me out?

I was reading something about using Web Deploy, but any direction will be highly appreciated, thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Install the package in IIS using IIS Manager.  An example with detailed instructions is here:  http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/UsingAWebDeployPackageToDeployToIISOnTheDevBoxAndToAThirdPartyHost.aspx
2. Install the package using the command line, with the deploy.cmd file which is designed to make that relatively easy comapred to using Web Deploy commands.  Instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104
3. Install the package using the command line, with raw Web Deploy commands. Complex to set up and I don't have a good link for this.

If you haven't considered one-click publish, you should consider that also. The package is created behind the scenes and Visual Studio does all the deployment work online.  For VS 2010, see this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337

The process has been much improved in VS 2012, and the RC version is available now (and the VS 2012 RC deployment functionality can be installed in VS 2010).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110)